What changes in swapping predictor and outcome variables in logistic regression
I have a dataset containing a variable representing the source of isolation of a bacterium, with 2 factors, along with multiple other binary variables indicating whether the bacterium is resistant to certain antibiotics (yes or no).
I have been performing logistic regressions, initially treating the source of isolation as the predictor.
glm <- glm(antibiotic1 ~ source, data = df, family = binomial()) 

However, I am considering the possibility of treating the source of isolation as the outcome instead. This way, I could use multiple antibiotic resistance variables as predictors, allowing me to group some antibiotics and perform a multivariate logistic regression to see if it yields better insights.
glm <- glm(source ~ antibiotic1 + antibiotic2, data = df, 
           family = binomial()) 

Is this approach feasible? What would change in terms of interpretability, and is it advisable to proceed in this manner?

What are you trying to find out? What is your research question(s)?  Also, whether it makes sense to treat source as a DV rather than an IV seems more like a substantive question than a statistical one. *Could& source "depend on" antibiotic?  (For some meaning of "depend"?  I don't thin so, but I am a data analyst, not a subjject matter expert.

I want to explore how differences in the source affect the resistance profile. No, the source can't "depend on" the antibiotic, but if I conduct the analysis this way, won't I be unable to interpret anything from the model?

I can't say for sure, but probably that analysis makes no sense. Your dependent variable will be "resistance profile" rather than any single measure of it, and I think you will need to consult with a statistician who also knows a bit about your field. There are ways to do this, but they are complicated.

It may help to read What is the difference between linear regression on y with x and x with y? In brief, the 2 analyses correspond to different questions. You need to decide which is the question you're interested in & run the analysis that corresponds to that. FWIW, if you only have 1 binary input & 1 binary output, either will yield the same p-value & there is a simple conversion b/t the 2 sets of parameter estimates (see: Relationship between regressing Y on X, and X on Y in logistic regression).

You can do this. This is similar to classification problems.
For example, the iris flower dataset where one models the type of flower based on the appearance (even though the appearance is the 'dependent' variable, but in statistical analysis the causal relationship, whether it is direct and which direction, is not always relevant).
For your binary resistance variables there are probably special solutions. Like for Principle Correspondence Analysis the binary/categorical alternative is Multiple Correspondence Analysis. Possibly you have similar alternatives for regression, classification or linear discriminant analysis like this (this part I do not know although the straight forward logistic regression can always be done, but might not be effective).
Also useful might be a heat-plot or something similar from which you could eye-ball whether there are potential correlations with different predictors. If you have bacteria that behave different and the effect of the source is opposite, then you might not notice this in a linear regressions where the opposite effects cancel out. Detecting the different potential groups/clusters of antibiotics resistance, then perform regression with those groups might work well. (or do this in one single go, which is I believe what a neural network effectively does by finding more complex patterns)
